# How to prevent the Output window in VS from disappearing?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, window, output

when I press Start to run my application in VS 2017 Community my Output window disappears. (I use it for i.e. Debug.WriteLine().) 
How to prevent this?
P.S.
The output window I`m refering to (not the command line window!):
[The output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fukRU.png)

Thanks
~Julius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After starting your application (debug mode), click View > Output (Ctrl + Alt + O) to show the output window. Stop your application and restart Visual Studio. Next time you run your application the output window should be visible automatically because Visual Studio remembers your opened windows in debug mode.

Comment: This is the correct guide! This answer should be [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: It works, just wanted to clarify for others that it also works for the "Start" button.

Comment: I just installed VS2022 and the output window wasn't displayed by default while running the application in debug mode.  After an hour of searching, this was the solution.  Thanks @Martin D.

Comment: @Joy nah, my issue was the docking setting. if restarting your application solves this problem, it sounds more like a bug in their app.

Answer (score 2):

Prevent it from autohiding using the 'Auto hide' icon in the right top corner (center of the three) of the Output window. That way it will stay docked.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a docked tab before running your program

Answer (score 0):

On Menu Bar:
Tools -> Options

A Pop-up window appears:

Debugging -> General -> Automatically close the console(scroll down to last)

Check the box and close

It applied to projects for visual studio.

Press Any Key to Continue...